# Migrating from jQuery to Zepto - $.data() - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I have some JavaScript, ending up with the below:

```
    $.fn.flips1         = function( options ) {

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'flips1' );

            if ( !instance ) {
                logError( "cannot call methods on flips1 prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;
            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for flips1 instance" );
                return;
            }

            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'flips1' );
            if ( !instance ) {
                $.data( this, 'flips1', new $.Flips1( options, this ) );
            }
        });

    }

    return this;

};
```

The code works fine with jQuery. After trying to port to Zepto (using a custom build with the data.js module included from Zepto Builder) I keep on getting a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" relating to the $.data section of the line `var instance = $.data( this, 'flips1' );` in the **else** statement.

Having looked around, there seems to be a lot of anecdotal evidence that Zepto 'works differently' in this regard, but no suggestions to get around issues.

Can anybody suggest how this should be implemented using Zepto?

Comment: did you try `$(this).data(...`?

Comment: thanks @charlietfl, but unfortunately this did not remedy the issue.